# "Why it is" vs "Why is it"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences:

1 ) Please tell me why **is it** like that. (should I put question mark at the end)

2 ) Please tell me why **it is** like that. (should I put question mark at the end)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first question is more inquisitive and could be rephrased to be:
"Please explain why it is like that."

The second question is of a slightly more confronting nature and could be rephrased to read:
"Please prove to me why it is like that."

Comment: Hi. Thank you. What about the question mark. Should I use it?

Comment: Please tell me "why is it like that?" / Please tell me why it is like that.

Answer (score 8):

1) Please tell me why is it like that. [grammatically incorrect unless the punctuation is changed.

Please tell me: Why is it like that?

The question: "Why is [etc.]" is a question form in English:

> - Why is the sky blue?
> - Why is it that children require so much attention?
> - Why is it [or some thing] like that?
>
> When that form is put into what is called indirect speech, it becomes:
>
> - Please tell me why the sky is blue.
> - Please tell me why children require so much attention.
> - Please tell me why it's like that.

The question form becomes a statement and therefore, the clause must follow the subject + verb rule for a declarative sentence with no subject and verb inversion.

2) Please tell me why it is like that. [correct]

Please tell me why [etc.]is not a question. Therefore, it would take no question mark. You can see that the first three examples above are questions and take a question mark at the end.